# '[(UIButton)]' does not have a member named 'enumerate' can anyone guide me for this error?

Tags: ios, swift, enumerate

```
for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate() <--getting my error here
                {
                    buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (44 + 5))
                    button.frame = buttonFrame
                }
            }
```

I have also tried enumerate(ratingButtons) but it doesn't add button in array

Answer (score 1):

take out the `.enumerate()` and it should work, also will have to change `(index, button)` to just `button`, since that array only contains UIButtons, and not tuples of index and buttons. you will have to manually count the iterations of the array if you need the index, otherwise setup a normal non-fast-enumerated for loop and get the button at the index manually

Comment: It gives me this error                                                                                    Cannot find an initializer for type 'CGFloat' that accepts an argument list of type '(_)'

Comment: not sure what you are doing but if i go `var x = CGFloat(45)` in my code it compiles fine

Comment: no problem, you should mark it as the answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me

```
var idx = 0
var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
for button in ratingButtons {
    buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(idx * (44 + 5))
    button.frame = buttonFrame
    idx = idx + 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just replace  **ratingButtons.enumerate()**  with **enumerate(ratingButtons)**
   this is the right wayto enumerate

```
    for (index, button) in enumerate(ratingButtons)
    {

        buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (buttonSize + 5))
        button.frame = buttonFrame
    }
```

for e.g 
enumerate() function which returns index of the item along with its value

```
import Cocoa

var strarr = [String]()

strarr.append("Mango")
strarr.append("Apple")
strarr += ["Banana"]

for (index, item) in enumerate(strarr) {
   println("Value at index = \(index) is \(item)")
}
```

Value at index = 0 is Mango
Value at index = 1 is Apple
Value at index = 2 is Banana